# How to make AMP-video a full page background?

Tags: html, css, video, background, amp-html

I have [this](https://www.recharge.ae) homepage with hero video as background. The video is an AMP video and it doesn't scale to mobile's full screen.

This is the code:

```
    <amp-video
          autoplay
          loop
          width="640"
          height="360"
          class="hero"
          layout="fill"
          poster="{{URL::asset('p1.webp')}}"
          >
          <source src="{{URL::asset('dubai.webm')}}"
          type="video/webm" />
          <source src="{{URL::asset('dubai.mp4')}}"
          type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="{{URL::asset('v1.ogg')}}"
          type="video/ogg" />
          {{-- <div fallback>
            <amp-img src="{{URL::asset('p1.webp')}}" width="640" height="360" alt="Dubai from above"></amp-img>
          </div> --}}
    </amp-video>

<!--blue filter over the video-->
<div class="v-text" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;background:rgba(2, 122, 195, 0.3)
;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;">

....
```

The problem is that I did something similar with [this](https://www.excurj.com) site and it works fine.

Comment: use layout responsive

Comment: I tried all layout types

Comment: I agree to use ["layout=responsive"](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/responsive_design#creating-a-responsive-layout), maybe you just need some reference to [embed videos](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/responsive_design#embedding-videos). Check out the link.

Comment: are these AMP pages?

Comment: It's AMP-powered meaning I use amp components like amp video and amp img

Answer (score 0):

Use **Web Inspector / DOM Explorer** (Keyboard Shortcut - Ctrl + Shift +C) in Chrome Browser's Debugging tools (Keyboard Shortcut - F12) to identify the exact **amp.css** class and attribute that is not letting your amp-image/amp-video scale to the entire page and then make it ***none*** in your **style amp-custom** block. *This is not an AMP suggested fix but only a workaround to get around the issue.*

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-overlay">
   <amp-video src="//localhost/videos/AirplaneFootage.mp4" loop autoplay layout="fill" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
position: absolute;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}

.video-overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
}

.video-overlay amp-video {        
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: auto;
}

.video-overlay amp-video .i-amphtml-fill-content {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: none;
}
```